# Why showing phantom std out error when using Nightmare.js or phantom.js to scrape website

Tags: node.js, web-crawler, phantomjs, nightmare

I'm trying to write a web-spider using phantom.js. However I got a lot of error message which I don't know why. My code is shown below:

- **Use Nightmare.js**:

  ```
  var Nightmare = require('nightmare');
  new Nightmare()
          .goto('http://www.amazon.com/Aroma-Housewares-ASP-137-3-Quart-Super/dp/B00024JQ3Q')
          .evaluate( function(){
            return document.getElementById('priceblock_ourprice').textContent;
          }, function( numAnchors ){
            console.log(numAnchors);
          })
          .run();
  ```
- **Use phantom.js**:

  ```
  var page = require('webpage').create();
  console.log('The default user agent is ' + page.settings.userAgent);
  page.open('http://www.amazon.com/Aroma-Housewares-ASP-137-3-Quart-Super/dp/B00024JQ3Q', function(status) {
    if (status !== 'success') {
      console.log('Unable to access network');
    } else {
      var ua = page.evaluate(function() {
        return document.getElementById('priceblock_ourprice').textContent;
      });
      console.log(ua);
    }
    phantom.exit();
  });
  ```

The error message are the same:

```
phantom stdout: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: ue.......
........
........
phantom stdout: TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'old_error_handler.apply')
.......
$35.99
```

I can got the result in the last line but there are so many errors shown above, what's the reason of that?

Comment: Did you ever find a way to disable it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will happen alot. The current PhantomJS (1.9.7) is based on an old QtWebkit fork comparable to Chrome 13 or Safari 5. The page in question quite possibly uses something in its JavaScript that PhantomJS doesn't understand. Most of the time this is nothing to worry about because the site will still function as intended.